# Transferring data from iPhone to Mac via Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone-sdk-3.1.3

Is there any way built into the iPhone SDK that allows devices to send data to a Mac over bluetooth? I know of GameKit, which allows data sharing between iPhones, but I haven't seen anything about an iPhone --> computer connection.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it ironic that you can send files over Bluetooth between Palm OS and Mac OS X using only built-in, supported tools, but you can't do anything like it between an iPhone and OS X?  *sigh*

Comment: Yeah its pretty ridiculous, file sharing is of the most basic of things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not seen this but I've seen several apps that open up a server port on the iphone that you can hit over http.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to send files with the iPhone.

You need to jailbreak the iPhone to do that.